# replacing numbering inside an ASCII file

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I want to erase the line numbering inside an ascii code file. The numbering starts with the Letter "N" and is followed by numbers as in example below.

```
N4980 G01 X = 0.75 Y = 14.97 Z = 0.07  
N5000 G01 X = 1.75 Y = 14.97 Z = 0.07  
N5020 G01 X = 1.75 Y = 22.00 Z = 0.07  
N5030 G01 X = 0.75 Y = 14.97 Z = 0.07 
N5060 G01 X = 32.75 Y = 14.97 Z = 0.07
```

i used powershell to replace individual strings but not a sequence of numbers. does anyone have a solution for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), use [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) to (conditionally) replace the line number, then pipe the whole thing to [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) to write it back to disk:

```
# read the whole file
$lines = Get-Content .\file.txt

# replace any leading `NXXXX ` sequence and write back to the file
$lines -replace '^N\d+\s+' |Set-Content .\file.txt
```